# Choose P independent pairs from an array of n numbers minimizing the sum of absolute difference of pairs

Tags: algorithm

There is an array of n positive integers. One has to choose p independent pairs from the array such that the sum of the absolute difference of pairs is minimized. n>=2*P. I have been thinking about the algorithm but could not come up with a solution for the problem.
e.g.
n = 7, p = 2
A = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7]
let say one choose two pairs (a1, a3) and (a4, a6). 
S = abs(a1-a2) + abs(a4-a6).
S should be minimum for these pairs compared to any other pairs are chosen if they are the answer.

What I think is I need to sort the array first and somehow I need to apply DP but am not able to get recursion.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please share what's you've been trying or researching so far?

Answer (score 0):

The state of the dynamic program on the sorted list could be: let `dp[i][k]` represent the best paring up to index `i` for `k` pairs, where `sorted_list[i]` is the larger member of a pair. Then:

```
dp[0][_] = Infinity
dp[i][1] = sorted_list[i] - sorted_list[i-1]
dp[i][k] = min(dp[i-1][k], sorted_list[i] - sorted_list[i-1] + dp[i-2][k-1])
  where 0 < k ≤ ceil(i / 2)
```